# Category navigation template

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to edit or add templates for navigation in categories ?

To be more specific, in the case of a news category that has multiple pages.

I would do something like this:

```
<footer class="footer">
<nav id="nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous">
        <a href="#" rel="prev">
            <span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">← Older</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-next">
        <a href="#" rel="next">
            <span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">Newer →</span> 
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also, I do not want to see the page numbers. Only "Older" and "Newer".

Thanks for your help !

---

### Update

Actually, I'm using modified Twenty Sixteen theme.

There is the code into category.php :

```
    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

        // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( '← older', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'newer →', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
```

When I try to replace this by something :

```
            // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( '← older', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'newer →', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );
```

I'm getting a 500 error.

I would like to put your code in this, but really don't know how to do it.

```
<nav id="post-pagination" class="navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="nav-previous">
    <?php next_posts_link( '← Older', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
</div>
<div class="nav-next">
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer →' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: there is not time associated with categories - what would 'older' or 'newer' mean for a category, and where do you want to get this information from?

Comment: To be more specific, in the case of a news category that has multiple pages. Newer and Older for articles in news category.

Comment: that would be normal pagination - start by looking into https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Always getting a 500 error when I try to change the parameters of the loop. I'm not familiar with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WordPress Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

You can use [`previous_posts_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) and [`next_posts_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link).

```
<nav id="post-pagination" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous">
        <?php next_posts_link( '← Older', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-next">
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer →' ); ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

*It's not important but Next and Previous have the opposite classes (`.nav-previous` on `next_posts_link()` & `.nav-next` on `previous_posts_link()`) because:*

> Because post queries are usually sorted in reverse chronological order, next_posts_link() usually points to older entries (toward the end of the set) and previous_posts_link() usually points to newer entries (toward the beginning of the set).

---

### Update

Based on your code, something like this should work (although I'm not sure what's wrong with the original `the_posts_pagination`?):

```
    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
    ?>

    <nav id="post-pagination" class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous">
            <?php next_posts_link( '← Older', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-next">
            <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer →' ); ?>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <?php
    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: This one seems to work. Although I have an issue with my CSS, float property "delete" padding-bottom. Footer have a padding of 16px, and nav-previous have a float to left. I don't know why the padding-bottom 16px don't show.

Comment: The precedent code was difficult to work with. My CSS is already applied on footer/nav. Also there was page numbers that I don't want.

Comment: Anyway, I will find something to resolve this myself. A big thanks for your help, really appreciated !